# Пустой Toolbox в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

Сел за изучение Windows Form приложений. Открыл [MSDN 4 урок](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx). Для того, чтобы добавить в приложение новые элементы, используется Toolbox.

1. Toolbox **на сайте**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Toolbox **у меня**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, почему он пустой и что надо, возможно, дополнительно скачать/установить? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я нажал правую кнопку на тулбоксе, включил ShowAll и все появилось.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ToolBox (Панель Элементов в русской редакции) в Visual Studio доступен только если у вас открыта форма в режиме конструктора. При переключении на любой другой файл или код формы, ToolBox не отображает элементы.

Кроме того, в последних версиях студии наблюдал баг с отображением элементов ToolBox-а и пунктов меню, студия что-то там забывает загрузить при запуске или не успевает, но ошибками не кидается, просто не показывает часть интерфейса. Более точной информации не имею, не копался, т.к. встречал только на виртуалке в терминальном режиме. Лечится перезапуском студии, со второго запуска догружается уже все.

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя уже есть какой-либо элемент на диалоговом окне, то даблкликни на него, после вернись на диалог. Элементы должны вернуться

Answer (score 0):

Если пропали элементы на "Панели элементов", нужно выполнить "Сброс панели элементов".

Для этого делаем правый клик по "Панели элементов" и выбираем соответствующий пункт меню. Или в том же меню нажимаем "Выбрать элементы..." и в открывшемся диалоге будет снизу справа кнопка "Сброс".